# how do I create the view for comments? (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to create a view to display the comments that will show like this

If someone comments under a post, it shows as "+1" that is clickable and it expands to display it. If another person comments, it changes to "+2".

Here's my comment form and I want to display the view underneath this:

```
<%= form_for([micropost, @comment]) do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :comment_content %>
  </div>
  <button class="btn" type="submit">
    Comment
  </button>
<% end %>
```

comments model

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :comment_content

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :micropost

  validates :comment_content, presence: true
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :micropost_id, presence: true  
end
```

Here's an example of how they're maintained in the database

```
#<Comment id: 11, user_id: 9, micropost_id: 40, cr
eated_at: "2013-03-10 22:03:36", updated_at: "2013-03-10 22:03:36", comment_cont
ent: "hello.">
```

Here's the code I'm trying to use in the view

```
<%= simple_format(comment.content) %>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to render comments from the database in a view or what are you asking exactly?

Comment: yes, I am trying to render comments from the database in a view and I'm trying to place it underneath the comment form

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: I created a view in comments/comment.html.erb where it uses the code "<%= simple_format(comment_content) %>". Then I am trying to render this view in my "_micropost.html.erb" with the line "<%= render 'comments/comment' %>". Is this the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you do something like this just below the `<% end %>` tag:

```
<a href="#" id="comment_count"> <%=  @micropost.comments.count.to_s %> </a> 
<div class="comments" style="display:none">
  <% for comment in @micropost.comments %>
   <%= render comment %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Then use some Javascript to display the div when the link is clicked.